# Creating min and max values and comparing them to timestamp values sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, date-arithmetic

I have a PostgreSQL database and I have a table that I am looking to query to determine which presses have been updated between the first cycle created_timestamp and the most recent cycle created_timestamp. Here is an example of the table, which is called event_log_summary.

```
press_id    cycle_number    created_timestamp
    1           1           2020-02-07 16:07:52
    1           2           2020-02-07 16:07:53
    1           3           2020-02-07 16:07:54
    1           4           2020-04-01 13:23:10
    2           1           2020-01-13 8:33:23
    2           2           2020-01-13 8:33:24
    2           3           2020-01-13 8:33:25
    3           1           2020-02-21 18:45:44
    3           2           2020-02-21 18:45:45
    3           3           2020-02-26 14:22:12
```

This is the query that I used to get me a three column output of press_id, mincycle, max_cycle, but then I want to compare the maxcycle created_timestamp to the mincycle created_timestamp and see if there is at least x amount of time between the two, say at least 1 day, I am unsure about how to implement that.

```
SELECT 
    press_id,
    MIN(cycle_number) AS minCycle,
    MAX(cycle_number) AS maxCycle
FROM
    event_log_detail
GROUP BY
    press_id
```

I have tried different things like using WHERE (MAX(cycle_number) - MIN(cycle_number > 1), but I am pretty new to SQL and don't quite fully know how to implement this. The output I am looking for, would have a difference of at least one day would be the following:

```
press_id
    1
    3
```

Presses 1 and 3 have their maximum cycle created_timestamp at least 1-day difference than their minimum cycle created_timestamp. I am just looking for the press_ids whose first cycle and the last cycle have a difference of at least 1 day, I don't need any other information on the output, just one column with the press_ids. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the smallest `cycle_number` always match to the smalles `created_timestamp`?

Comment: Yes the smallest cycle_number always is the smallest or oldest created_timestamp. The largest cycle_number will always be the largest or most recent created_timestamp. I just want to see presses whose most recent created_timestamp versus the oldest timestamp is at least 1 day difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a HAVING clause:

```
select press_id, 
       max(created_timestamp) - min(created_timestamp) as diff
from event_log_detail
group by press_id
having max(created_timestamp) > min(created_timestamp) + interval '1 day';
```

Comment: I tried that and I got the following error:

ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer + interval
LINE 7: HAVING max(cycle_number) > MIN(cycle_number) + interval '1 d...
                                                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Thank you, that worked beautifully! Thanks for the help!